# Javascript - JQuery : Cannot find id and .html("") or getElementById and set the innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getelementbyid

I'm new to jQuery and can't add `innerhtml` to a div.

I have tried `getElementById` and also `$('').html()`.

My javascript

```
var dishes = arg;

var starterDish = dishes[0];
var mainDish = dishes[1];
var dessertDish = dishes[2];

location.href=$('#finishButton').attr('href');
//The new HTML file

alert($('#starterDishName').html());
// will only return unidentified

$('#starterDishName').html(starterDish.name);
$('#starterDishPrep').html(starterDish.description);

$('#mainDishName').html(mainDish.name);
$('#mainDishPrep').html(mainDish.description);

$('#dessertDishName').html(dessertDish.name);
$('#dessertDishPrep').html(dessertDish.description);

run4 = false;
```

and the finish.html file:

```
 </div>
    <div id="starterDishName" align="center"> <h3>blablabla</h3></div>
    <div id="starterDishPrep" align="center"> </div>
    <div id="mainDishName" align="center"> <h3></h3></div>
    <div id="mainDishProp" align="center">  </div>
    <div id="dessertDishName" align="center"> <h3> </h3></div>
    <div id="dessertDishProp" align="center">  </div>
</div>
```

I think the problem is located: `location.href=$('#finishButton').attr('href');`

and that the new html file wont allow me to use the ID's get?

**QUESTION:**
How can I get the id of the new html file and change the `innerhtml` of it from my code's perspective?

Comment: Where is the element with the id `finishButton` in your code? And is your JavaScript within another function that you're not showing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have this in a JavaScript file as you wrote: "*My .js*". And if you have included it in the `head`-section of your HTML the script is executed immediately and the selectors are not aware of all the HTML elements. Using jQuery you can simply wrap everything into a closure as this will get executed after the DOM is parsed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your logic goes here
});
```

Comment: Thank you!

It works i included the .js file in the header of the second index.html file and then called the function from another js function. I guess my problem was that i couldnt have 2 .js files included in two diffrent headers , because it makes conflicts with imports. 

THanks

Answer (score 0):

`var id = document.getElementById('id').innerHTML;`

Comment: Have tried:
document.getElementById('starterDishName').innerHTML = starterDish.name;

But it wont display anything.

Comment: Have you tried `starterDish.tagName` or `starterDish.nodeName`? Tell me if not, and I know one more trick to try.